# How to redirect to url by cancel button in django-crispy-forms?

Tags: django, forms, model-view-controller, view, django-crispy-forms

```
class StudentCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Student
    template_name = "students/students_edit.html"
    form_class = StudentCreateForm

def get_success_url(self):
    return u'%s?status_message=Студент успішно створений' % reverse('home')

def post(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
    if request.POST.get('cancel_button'):
        messages.info(self.request, u"Створення скасовано")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            u'%s?status_message=Створення скасовано'
            % reverse('home'))
    else:
        messages.success(self.request, u"Студент успішно створений") 
        return super(StudentCreateView, self).post(
            request,*arg, **kwargs)
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(StudentCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['meta'] = u'Додавання студента'
    context['headtext'] = context['meta']
    return context
```

In this view i check in post function if is clicked cancel button

```
self.helper.layout[-1] = FormActions(
        Submit('add_button',u'Зберегти', css_class='btn btn-primary'),
        Submit('cancel_button', u'Скасувати'),
        )
```

Only on createview submit cancel is not working properly. On click it tries to check form and crispy answers me to solve all problems on form when i want to cancel. I've changed submit to button and button cancel have no effect at all. I've found a variant on stackoverflow with adding onclick method to button, but it's not for me(
When i cancel or post form on redirected window info message tells me a status of posting or canceling. So when i tried onclick method it pushed on past page, so info message wasn't shown.
How to fix cancel on CreateView?

Answer (score 8):

Add `Cancel` button and use `window.location.href` within `onclick` event:

```
self.helper.add_input(Button('cancel', 'Cancel', css_class='btn-primary',
                             onclick="window.location.href = '{}';".format(reverse('your-cancel-url-name'))))
```

Comment: If you need to go to detail page, use _reverse('your-detail-page-url-name', args=[self.instance.id])_

Comment: For me this pattern is raising an `ImproperlyConfigured` error - "The included URLconf 'project.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import." My project site worked fine before this alteration, so I don't think it's an issue with urls.py

Answer (score 4):

Another way if you prefer is to pass the HTML as is:

```
    from crispy_forms.layout import HTML
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                'Title',
                'field1',
                'field2',
                'field3'
            ),
            FormActions(
                        Submit('save', 'Save'),
                        HTML('<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/">Cancel</a>')
                    )
     )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
self.helper.layout.append(
            FormActions(
                submit,
                Submit('cancel_button', u'Скасувати', css_class="btn btn-link"),
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, but works:

```
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import FormActions
from crispy_forms.layout import Fieldset, HTML, Layout, Submit

rows = [el for el in self.fields]  # self == form
rows.append(
    FormActions(
        Submit('Save', _('Save')),
        HTML(f'<a href="{reverse("focov:choose-regulation")}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">{_("Cancel")}</a>'),
    css_class="row"),
)
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Fieldset('', *rows),
)
```

Comment: maybe newest version has new features for that.